# copying constness in templates fails strangely based on type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I wrote a template to copy constness of a pointer argument for C++11:

```
template<typename S, typename D>
struct copy_const {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_const<S>::value,
          typename std::add_const<D>::type,
          typename std::remove_const<D>::type>::type type;
};
```

To be used in a method like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U,
    class=typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, char>::value>::type>
typename copy_const<T, U>::type pointer(T*, U);
```

I am getting different behaviors based on the type of U:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((char *)0, 0)), int>::value,
              "bad pointer 1");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((const char *)0, 0)), const int>::value,
              "bad pointer 2");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((const char *)0, 0)), int>::value,
              "bad pointer 3");

error: static_assert failed "bad pointer 2"
```

Basically, I am getting "int" return value regardless of the constness of T, even though I verified that T gets resolved to const char.

Now if I change U to some other class, the constness is copied correctly:

```
struct V{};
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((char *)0, V())), V>::value,
              "bad pointer 4");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((const char *)0, V())), const V>::value,
              "bad pointer 5");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer((const char *)0, V())), V>::value,
              "bad pointer 6");

error: static_assert failed "bad pointer 6"
```

Even though the following asserts for the copying of constness succeed:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(0), int>::value, "bad type");
static_assert(std::is_same<std::add_const<int>::type, const int>::value,
              "bad const 1");
static_assert(std::is_same<const int, copy_const<const int, int>::type>::value,
              "bad const 2");
```

Is this a compiler error, or am I ignoring something?

Answer (score 3):

const qualifiers of scalar types are ignored on the return type of a function.  For example:

```
static const int returns_const_int();

int main()
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(returns_const_int()), const int>::value,
        "not const"
    );
}
```

Causes

```
warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
    [-Wignored-qualifiers]
static const int returns_const_int();

static assertion failed: not const
```

So in the cases where `pointer()` is declared to return a `const int`, it is actually returning a non-const int.

The same as not true for class types however.